# Canonical expression of "union" or "variant record"?

Tags: oracle, database-design, plsql

Suppose I have some data where several types need to be expressed in one table.  For example, an "events" table might have entries for these user events: ("login", "logout", "create", "delete").  Of course, the associated information for each event will vary by event type.

Currently "events" has (event_num, event_type), and a table for each event type, discriminated by event_type.

Is there a canonical way to express this in Oracle? in generic SQL?

Answer (score 1):

A relational purist would say that every different event is it's own entity. It sounds like you're half-following that model already (with a table for each type.) The parent `events` table really adds little in practice. You can't really `UNION` rows from tables that have different schemas and "overloaded" foreign keys are almost always troublesome.

Most commonly, I've seen these "event" tables consolidated into a single "log" table. It becomes much easier to compile all the events and present in the application. Historically the different attributes of logged events were expressed as a free text field that contained additional info but I would suggest this would be a good use for the XML data type.

You would end up with an event table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE events 
(
    Event_num int,
    event_date datetime,
    user_id int,
    ... //other attributes common to all events
    event_data XMLTYPE
)
```

This allows you to consolidate all your data in one table while still allowing different attributes for different events. This is one of the common use-cases of XML in a relational DB and is an improvement on the older method for storing event-log data.